# How to add multiple filters on a Vue component's data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, filtering, vue-props

I am trying to add multiple filters to a component. For example, a user can select a category and the results will be filtered. Additionally, since I have a search filter implement, how can I combine other filters with the join filter? For example, If I type 'Winter', and select a category that does not contain winter (a holidays filters), no results would show.

I've tried looking this up on Google, but I am only able to implement one filter at a time.

**UPDATE**
I changed my computed properites to be a general filteredItems array. Now, I am able to set filters, however, when first load the page, nothing appears until I select a filter. Any ideas on how this can be fixed?

```
<template>
  <div class="cards">
    <CountdownCard
      v-for="(event, index) in filteredItems"
      :key="index"
      :event="event"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CountdownCard from '@/components/CountdownCard'
import EventBus from '@/components/EventBus'

export default {
  components: {
    CountdownCard
  },
  data() {
    return {
      events: [
        {
          title: 'Autum',
          date: 'September 22, 2020',
          emoji: '',
          type: 'holiday',
          year: 2020,
          month: 8,
          day: 22,
          hour: 0,
          minute: 0
        },
        {
          title: 'Winter',
          date: 'December 21, 2020',
          emoji: '⛄️',
          type: 'holiday',
          year: 2020,
          month: 11,
          day: 21,
          hour: 0,
          minute: 0
        }
      updateSearch: ''
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    EventBus.$on('search-countdowns', search => {
      this.updateSearch = search
    })
  },
  computed: {
    filteredItems: function() {
      return this.events
        .filter(event => {
          return event.title
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(this.updateSearch.toLowerCase())
        })
        .filter(event => {
          return event.type == this.filter
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

As you can see, I have a filteredHolidays filter that, when a button is clicked, would filter out any non-holiday results and display only holidays.

Here is the button component, that when clicked, should filter the data in my first component

```
<template>
  <button>{{ filter.name }}</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    filter: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide an online working example? I think I have a clue of what to do for what you want, but it would be good to work on it in the real example.

Comment: @Pipetus, sure, check out my github repo! https://github.com/tyler-morales/countdown. Thanks!

Comment: I meant something like a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/vue) :)

Comment: @Pipetus I don't think I am able to create that, I have too many interconnected components and something would break. However, I just updated my code above. What do you think of the filteredItems computed property? And, do you have any suggestions to display all items at the first load of the page?

Comment: Ok, anyway, I was about to post something similar to the answer you now have.

Comment: For the new problem, I assume you need to populate the `filteredItems` for the first time, probably as part of `mounted` or as a condition in `filteredItems`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of listing multiple computed properties for each filter, make a general computed property called filteredItems and loop through that in the template.
`v-for="(event, index) in filteredItems"`

```
computed: {
    filteredItems: function() {
      return this.events
        .filter(event => {
          return event.title
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(this.updateSearch.toLowerCase())
        })
        .filter(event => {
          return event.type == this.filter
        })
    }
  }
```